# Output array from subarray inside multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create an array from a subarray inside $array. I have managed to get almost what I want I want through a combination of operations, but better would be to do it in one go.

```
print_r($array)
```

outputs

```
Array ( 
    [food] => Array ( [taste] => Sweet [color] => Green ) 
    [drink] => Array ( [smell] => Lemon [type] => Still ) 
    [daisy] => Array ( [color] => Pink [travel] => Paris ) 
    [mike] => Array ( [weight] => 150 [car] => Ford ) 
    [hassan] => Array ( [color] => Red [type] => City ) 
    [results] => Array ( 
        [tabular] => Array ( 
            [time] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 6 ) 
                [1] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 3 ) 
                [2] => Array ( [name] => Excellent [value] => 22 )
                [3] => Array ( [name] => Good [value] => 12 ) 
                [4] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 8 ) 
                [5] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 0 )
            ) 
        )
    ) 
)
```

How can I get this?

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 6 )        
    [1] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 3 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [name] => Excellent [value] => 22 )
    [3] => Array ( [name] => Good [value] => 12 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 8 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 0 )
)
```

I tried

```
$sliced = (array_slice($array,5));
$reduced = array_reduce($sliced, 'array_merge', array());
$output = array_column($reduced,"time");
print_r($output);
```

gives me

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 6 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 3 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [name] => Excellent [value] => 22 )
        [3] => Array ( [name] => Good [value] => 12 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [name] => Average [value] => 8 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [name] => Poor [value] => 0 )
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Reassign it in foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r($array['results']['tabular']['time'])`